# Does the Raspberry Pi 2 model B v1.1 have an internal RTC?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I work with Raspberry Pi 2 model B v1.1 and I searched about a RTC to keep time even in the case of a power outage or a loss of internet connection. I found that I must buy a RTC chip with a battery. But recently I heard that my Raspberry Pi already contains a RTC. But is it right? If so, where is its location? I don't see anything called RTC on my chip.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think it has an RTC and I doubt you'd find a chip labelled "RTC" in case it did. It would probably just have a manufacturer's logo and a combination of numbers and letters that don't spell anything meaningful; eg. ds3231 or ds1307. If you get an external RTC, go for the ds3231 - it's much better than the ds1307. Just out of curiosity, do you have a source for the claim that the *"pi already contains RTC"*?

Comment: my friend works with RoboticX "group pf people who sell electronics materials". She said "Rpi contains RTC" but i doubt a bout this thing!

Comment: i found ds1307 but i will take your suggestion to buy ds3231 thanks

Comment: Ok, you should set your friend straight! :) As I'm sure you know, an RTC needs a battery or a super-capacitor to work so it's pretty easy to check. No battery, no RTC. I've added a ds3231 to one of my Pis for this reason; it's pretty easy, cheap and effective.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome

Comment: What do you think about PiFace- shim RTC ? it is 19$ on www.ebay.com website it is an expensive but it is an easy to connect it with pins check it and tell me is it better than ds3231 ? or check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBUGtiDrHKc  ... :)

Comment: Interesting... Didn't know that one. Checking it out now. My 1st impression is that they seem functionally similar. The ds3231 is made by Maxim, the MCP9740N is Microchip but both use i2c and are quite accurate. One difference might be driver support: ds3231 is very common so working drivers are out there already. The MCP7940n isn't as common so it might be harder to find drivers. One thing I know for sure, though, is that I wouldn't buy from the western vendors that charge 10-20x more than their Asian counterparts unless I was in a real hurry. $20 for an RTC just seems too expensive.

Comment: Yeah, I'd still go for the ds3231. Your requirements may differ but I wouldn't gain anything from choosing the PiFace shim. Of course, if you get [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/For-Arduino-DS3231-AT24C32-IIC-Module-Precision-Real-Time-Clock-Quare-Memory-/262123918224) you'll need to connect it via 4 breadboard/Dupont wires whereas the PiFace shim doesn't need wires. There are many other details but the comment section isn't the place for that. Anyway, here's a [simple guide to setting up the ds3231 on Raspbian](http://www.elevendroids.com/2012/12/setting-up-hardware-rtc-in-raspbian/)

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain there is not an RTC chip built-in: "One of the complaints Pi users have is that there's no built-in hardware clock on the Pi." (Source: https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/blog/2015/04/22/raspberry-pi-2-piface-rtc-shim-testing).

However, I was able to find a nice [tutorial](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi) on how to install your own.

Comment: thanks, i already searched a bout the installing and rtc-ds1307

Answer (score 1):

None of the Raspberry Pi models have a built-in real time clock.

Answer (score 0):

As cool as Raspberry Pi's are the B+ and 2 models do not have a physical RTC.  According to the RaspberryPi.org website, [Where I found this blurb,](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#performanceRTC) the decision was made not to include RTC's because they wanted to keep the cost down.

"5. WHY IS THERE NO REAL-TIME CLOCK (RTC)?

The expectation is that non-network-connected units will have their clocks updated manually at startup. Adding an RTC is surprisingly expensive once you have factored in batteries, area and components, and would have pushed us above our target price. You can add one yourself using the GPIO pins if you’d like an interesting electronics project. -Performance and Cost Considerations -Top"

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**
I'm like you, and I have a real need for a RTC.  I'm currently building this that I found on Instructables.  [Link Here, Check it Out](http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-RTC-DS1307-Module-and-use-with-Raspberry-Pi/)

Answer (score 0):

I think we've all concluded that none of the Pis have RTCs so to keep time without network and the ntp daemon, an external RTC is needed. I recommend getting the ds3231 over the ds1307. The price difference is negligible - you can find both units for ~$1 including free shipping at your favourite Shenzen outlet. The important difference is that the ds3231 is more accurate due to its built-in temperature compensation.

Quotes from [this site](http://tronixstuff.com/2014/12/01/tutorial-using-ds1307-and-ds3231-real-time-clock-modules-with-arduino/) where you can also find some code for interfacing with both units:

*"The DS1307 used in the first module works very well, however the external temperature can affect the frequency of the oscillator circuit which drives the DS1307’s internal counter."*

*"The DS3231 is much more accurate, as it has an internal oscillator which isn’t affected by external factors – and thus is accurate down to a few minutes per year at the most."*