# Issue with setting job using cronTab in raspberry

Tags: python

i have this issue

i want to use crontab to schedule job using python language 
but NOT adding this job manually using `crontab -e`

So i need to do this from file named server.py :

```
from crontab import CronTab, CronSlices

user_cron=CronTab(user=True)
cmd = 'sudo python ON.py' #ON is the file.py which i want to run it
job = user_cron.new(cmd)
job.setall('4 20 * * *') #it is at 20:4
user_cron.write()        # to write job in the cron
job.run()                #to run job
print user_cron.render() # to print job on the screen
              ## result when print is 4 20 * * * sudo python ON.py
```

My issue is: ON.py will run if i run server.py even the time is not 20:4 !!! 
it must run the ON.py just at this time not other !!!
any help about this issue !!

Comment: Does it run correctly apart from also running when you run server.py? I know you're asking about the python way of doing it but you could also do it in shell - at least that works pretty reliably in my experience (although not using `crontab -e` is generally discouraged, as you seem to know)

Comment: yes it works, but not at the specific time, it is run always while running the server.py : i try to do this: run server.py if current time is equal to 20:4 then run ON.py else don't run ON.py, but in my case the ON.py always run!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely... *"yes it works, but not at the specific time"* Cron has *one* purpose: running things at specific times; if it doesn't do that, it's not working. You know you could simply write it in a bash/shell script and call that from python, right? It would be easier than dealing with python-cron, I think. You could also have a single cron entry that never changes but reads the contents of a file or runs a python script every minute; this file/script could then decide if the time is right to execute something else. That way you could leave cron alone completely.

Comment: I know how to write it in shell but i want as i wrote above....as in my example. my case is: android application send "turn ON room light at 8:00 this night " so server.py must write this command in crontable without human intervention and when time become 8:00 night it will ON"

Comment: Ok, it's up to you, of course, but I've done this exact thing and something more complicated with only one cron entry that simple ran a python script every minute. All the logic was in the python script that took input from javascript/html and android. I used a json file for saving "turn on at 8 'o clock"-commands from the web and read it from the python script... Just a suggestion. Btw. you should accept some answers to your other questions; like the one on [RTCs and raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161221/does-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b-v1-1-have-an-internal-rtc)

Comment: Can you advice me, or direct me to some tutorial ! because the tutorials which i provide above didn't work correctly with me, i don't understand "only one cron entry".

Comment: I didn't find a tutorial that did it - maybe I should write it. I made a single cron entry like so: `* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/username/minute_script.py` (runs every minute) and in "minute_script.py", I had a time range check that used the `datetime` module. The user picks on/off times on a website and these are saved as json on the raspi via php. E.g. `{"lights":{"t_on": {"hour": 20,"min": 4},"t_off": {"hour": 22,"min": 33}}}`. The python script then turns lights on/off depending on whether or not the current time is within the interval. It's a little complicated to explain it all here.

Comment: exact thing i did from android app i send from app as you send and in my script python i get "hour" and "minutes" BUT to put them in crontabale, now i understood your way.... you try to run script.py every minute to catch the schedule time, right? but i try to do this from opposite side, i want script print (4 20 * * * sudo python ON.py) to make it repeater.

Comment: *"you try to run script.py every minute to catch the schedule time, right?"* Yes, sort of. But instead of only trying to "catch" a single minute, e.g. 20:04, I use an interval/range. You say "turn lights on if the time is 20:04" and my script says "turn lights on if the time is *higher* than 20:04 and *lower* than 23:04" (3 hours lights on and 21 hours lights off per day, every day).

Comment: yes very good as i understood, now if you want to make this action for only this day!! you will not need to repeat this action right? But as we know CronTable always repeat the command which saved in it. I think we can delete this command from crontable after complete right? or you have better suggestion ? i like to hear from you.

Comment: Yes, cron repeats everything. If you want to schedule a command that runs only *once* (like "turn on the lights today at 20:04 but *not* tomorrow") you will need something a little different from the system I described. Cron is still a good choice but it should run a bash or python script every minute - no need to edit crontab all the time. The bash/python script checks a "task list" or a queue and deletes every task after running (that way, the tasks only run once). The logic could simply be: "if time_now == time_to_run: run_command(); delete_task()"

Comment: thanks very much i will try everything tomorrow , i'm lucky to find interesting information from you :)

Comment: My friend, can i ask another question about this topic if you don't mind ! i still think about it "after server receive only one task {"lights":{"t_on": {"hour": 20,"min": 4},"t_off": {"hour": 22,"min": 33}}} it will saved as json in server side,and will run every day right? But if client/android app send another task after the first one, with another time, and he want to repeat two tasks, so server will still has the first task or it will lost?

Comment: You're welcome - it's an interesting topic :) However, it's impossible to answer your question without knowing how you've implemented it. I would need to see the code. You could ask a new question and include your code, your current output and your desired output so people have something to work with. You're also welcome to write me an email if you want to discuss this further off-site (the address is on my profile page) but we should try to keep stack overflow on-topic. I couldn't get python CronTab to work, so I probably can't help with *this* particular question